# Volkswagen push-button start

Tags: vw, parts, jetta

Does anyone know the name of the part on the steering column in push-button start Volkswagens? The thing you're supposed to hold your fob up to if the battery is dying in order to get one more start. Some moron broke it in our Jetta trying to start the car with the key instead of pushing the button and for the life of me I can't figure out what it's called so I can search for a replacement part.

Comment: What year Jetta? I hope the moron is a family member or friend, so you can send them the (probably) enormous bill for rebuilding the steering column. As far as I can tell from other models, it's part of the steering lock, and interfaces to the immobilizer. Replacement may involve removing the steering wheel and airbag - not a job for beginners.

Comment: @PeteCon - If the OP's other question is any indicator, it's a 2015 VW Jetta.

Comment: It is a 2015. It was a place my husband took it to get the oil changed. Most people ask how to start the car once they see there's no hole for the key, but not this guy! Luckily, the place is going to pay to fix it now. Sometimes yelling pays off.